# How to use a select within an inner join

Tags: sql, teradata

I did this UPDATE to put 1 or 0 in the column GESTOR_ATIVO:

```
UPDATE DIM_GESTORES 
FROM
    (SELECT 
    G.COD_EMPRESA
,   G.MATRICULA
,   GES.SITUACAO_GESTOR
,   CASE 
        WHEN GES.MATRICULA = G.MATRICULA AND
        GES.COD_EMPRESA = G.COD_EMPRESA THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END GESTOR_ATIVO
        FROM DIM_GESTORES G 
        LEFT JOIN AUX_TESTE_GESTORES GES ON -- replace this table with select
        GES.MATRICULA = G.MATRICULA AND
        GES.COD_EMPRESA = G.COD_EMPRESA) AS CAD
SET GESTOR_ATIVO = CAD.GESTOR_ATIVO 
WHERE DIM_GESTORES.COD_EMPRESA = CAD.COD_EMPRESA 
AND DIM_GESTORES.MATRICULA = CAD.MATRICULA
;
```

And I would like to use this SELECT to replace the AUX_TESTE_GESTORES (which is the same thing as this SELECT here)

```
SELECT
CAD.MATRICULA,
CAD.COD_EMPRESA,
GES.NOME_N,
GES.NIVEL_GESTOR,
CAD.EMAIL,
CAD.PROFISSAO,
CURRENT_DATE AS DAT_ATUALIZACAO

FROM STG_CADASTRO_001 AS CAD
INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT
            STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N1 AS MATRICULA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.COD_EMPRESA_N1 AS COD_EMPRESA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.NOME_N1 AS NOME_N,
            'N1' AS NIVEL_GESTOR
        FROM
            STG_HIERARQUIA
        WHERE
            (STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N1 IS NOT NULL)
         
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT
            STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N2 AS MATRICULA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.COD_EMPRESA_N2 AS COD_EMPRESA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.NOME_N2 AS NOME_N,
            'N2' AS NIVEL_GESTOR
        FROM
            STG_HIERARQUIA
        WHERE
            (STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N2 IS NOT NULL)
        
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT
            STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N3 AS MATRICULA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.COD_EMPRESA_N3 AS COD_EMPRESA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.NOME_N3 AS NOME_N,
            'N3' AS NIVEL_GESTOR
        FROM
            STG_HIERARQUIA
        WHERE
            (STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N3 IS NOT NULL)
                
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT
            STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N4 AS MATRICULA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.COD_EMPRESA_N4 AS COD_EMPRESA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.NOME_N4 AS NOME_N,
            'N4' AS NIVEL_GESTOR
        FROM
            STG_HIERARQUIA
        WHERE
            (STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N4 IS NOT NULL)
               
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT
            STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N5 AS MATRICULA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.COD_EMPRESA_N5 AS COD_EMPRESA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.NOME_N5 AS NOME_N,
            'N5' AS NIVEL_GESTOR
        FROM
            STG_HIERARQUIA
        WHERE
            (STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N5 IS NOT NULL)    
            
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT
            STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N6 AS MATRICULA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.COD_EMPRESA_N6 AS COD_EMPRESA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.NOME_N6 AS NOME_N,
            'N6' AS NIVEL_GESTOR
        FROM
            STG_HIERARQUIA
        WHERE
            (STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N6 IS NOT NULL)
        
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT
            STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N7 AS MATRICULA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.COD_EMPRESA_N7 AS COD_EMPRESA_N,
            STG_HIERARQUIA.NOME_N7 AS NOME_N,
            'N7' AS NIVEL_GESTOR
        FROM
            STG_HIERARQUIA
        WHERE
            (STG_HIERARQUIA.MATRICULA_N7 IS NOT NULL)) AS GES
    ON GES.MATRICULA_N = CAD.MATRICULA
    AND GES.COD_EMPRESA_N = CAD.COD_EMPRESA
```

I turned this SELECT above into a new table AUX_TESTE_GESTORES but I want to delete it using just this query above along with UPDATE, is it possible to do this or do I need the table I created to generate update?

Comment: Seems you want to wrap it in a *Derived Table* `LEFT JOIN (Your Select) AS GES ON`

Comment: @dnoeth i did that before asking the question however eland returns that there is no column GESTOR_ATIVO: 

`Executed as Single statement.  Failed [3810 : 42S22] Column/Parameter 'GES.GESTOR_ATIVO' does not exist. `

Comment: @Akina sorry, i've already edited the tags, tks

Comment: I would run the inner select from under the UPDATE first to see if this resolves. Also, try to remove table shortnames, and see if fully-qualified column naming makes a difference.